# Use get_object() and aggregate() in DetailView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a `DetailView` in Django. In my template I'm printing the fields in my object dictionary, e.g. `object.full_name`.

But I also want some aggregates belonging to the object. If say I have a model `Person` and a model `Group` and the model `Group` has a foreign key to `Person`, can I then override `get_object()` in my `DetailView` to be something like:

```
def get_object(self):
    return super(DetailView, self).get_object().aggregate(num_groups=Count('group_set'))
```

I've tested my suggestion but it doesn't work. I guess there must be some work-around to do this without having to override `get_context_data()` and populating variables as `context['num_groups'] = Group.objects.filter(person=self.object).count()`. This could be done but if I have more than one model with a foreign key to `Person` it would be smarter if I could just accomplish this with an aggregate as in my code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DetailView.get_object()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) returns model instance instance not the queryset. But you can populate any attribute of the object:

```
def get_object(self):
    object = super(PersonView, self).get_object()
    object.num_groups = object.group_set.all().count()
    return object
```

Note the `PersonView` in the `super()` call.  You should use the name of your class view here.

If you want get multiple counts related to person then you can do it with something like this:

```
counts = Person.objects.filter(pk=object.pk).aggregate(
                  num_groups=Count('group_set'), num_items=Count('item_set'))
object.num_groups = counts['num_groups']
object.num_items = counts['num_items']
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Can I use a notation similiar to your's with a nested relationsship? I mean that I can write `aggregate(num_items=Count('group_set__item_set')` but can I also write `self.person.group_set.item_set.count()`?

Comment: `_set` is a property of an instance which returns a queryset. This means that you can't chain such properties as `group_set.item_set`.

Comment: My example will produce 2 queries.  You can reduce it to one by reimplementing the logic of `SingleObjectMixin.get_object()` model. But I advise you not to do this.  These two queries are pretty cheap.

Comment: But I want to calculate multiple counts related to the person. If it was only those two queries I wouldn't be worried

Comment: You can aggregate any number of counts in the second query.  See the updated answer.